# Javascript how to replace $index

Tags: javascript

I have a string with indexes `$1` and I would like to replace them with values. Something like this:

```
const index = 1; // This is dynamic, so we need to use this index variable

let myStr = 'Hi there $1';
myStr = myStr.replace(/\$1/g, 'FRIEND');
console.log(myStr); // Hi there FRIEND
```

The above works, but now I need to replace the `1` with `index`:

```
const index = 1; // This is dynamic, so we need to use this index variable
let myStr = 'Hi there $1';
myStr = myStr.replace(new RegExp('$' + index, 'g'), 'FRIEND');
myStr = myStr.replace(new RegExp('\$' + index, 'g'), 'FRIEND');
console.log(myStr);
```

Neither of the above ideas work? I can use a substring solution, but I was hoping `String.replace()` would be useable.

Comment: An unescaped `$` means "End of string" in a regular expression - you must escape it with a literal backslash passed to the constructor (which requires 2 typed backslashes, if using anything other than `String.raw`)

Comment: That is definitely not a duplicate question. How would I ever google `Why do regex constructors need to be double escaped?` when I don't even know that is the answer to my question...but thank you it did solve my question